# php - FILTER _VALIDATE_EMAIL check

Tags: php

I have a PHP script where I want to verify a valid email address using `filter_var()` but it is not working.

**html form:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>CRUD Operations</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"><!--container-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="form-element">
            <div id="headings">
                <h1>PHP Contact Form</h1>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="operations.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <span>Name:</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br><br>
            <span>Email:</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="mail" value=""><br><br>
            <span>Gender:</span><br>
            &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">&nbsp;Male
            &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">&nbsp;Female<br><br>
               <span>Message</span><br>
           <div id="message">
            <textarea cols="36" rows="4" name="message"></textarea><br>
           </div>
           <div id="submit">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
           </div>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

**php code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>CRUD Operations</title>
</head>
<?php
include_once('config.php');
$name = $mail = $gender = $message = '';
$email_err = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];

    if(!isset($_POST['gender'])){
    }
    else {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    }

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(empty($name) || empty($mail) || empty($gender)|| empty($message)) {
        if(empty($name)){
            echo'<div class="error">*Dear User fill the Name field properly</div>';
        } 

        if(empty($mail)){
            echo'<div class="error">*Dear User fill the Email field properly</div>';
        }
        else {
            if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $email_err = "*valid Email is required";
            }
        }

        if(empty($gender)){
            echo'<div class="error">*Dear User please select your gender</div>';
        }

        if(empty($message)){
            echo'<div class="error">*Dear User please Leave your Message</div>';
        }
    }
    else {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`name`, `mail`, `gender`, `message`) VALUES('".$name."','".$mail."','".$gender."','".$message."')");

        if($query) {
            echo '<div class="success">Congratulations You Are Registered Successfully</div>';
            echo '<a href="users.php">View Records</a>';
        }
        else {
            echo 'not';
        }
    }
}
?>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"but it is not working ... plz fix my issue"* what is your issue to begin with?

Comment: by "not working", do you mean, email field is accepted even if it is not an email ?

Comment: yes @TareqMahmood. even when i give garbage value in email field, it accepts and registers the user.does not show error on invalid email address

Comment: @muhammaduzman check creanium's answer and let us know if still you cannot fix.

Comment: Read the documentation for **empty**.  A better test would be to use **isset** on the $_POST variables and perhaps the length after you trim the values.  Then you can check the email address for validity.

Comment: not working.i did that too

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the validation error to the `$email_err` variable, but you're not doing anything with that variable after that.

But more importantly, the `filter_var()` call will never be hit. You have it in the block that checks for any of `$name` `$mail` `$gender` `$messsage` are empty. So the only way to get your code to do an email validation would be if someone entered an email address, but left gender blank.

You need to move the `filter_var()` call out of that block:

```
if(empty($name) || empty($mail) || empty($gender)|| empty($message)) {
    if(empty($name)){
        echo'<div class="error">*Dear User fill the Name field properly</div>';
    } 

    if(empty($mail)){
        echo'<div class="error">*Dear User fill the Email field properly</div>';
    }

    if(empty($gender)){
        echo'<div class="error">*Dear User please select your gender</div>';
    }

    if(empty($message)){
        echo'<div class="error">*Dear User please Leave your Message</div>';
    }
}
elseif(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo'<div class="error">*valid Email is required</div>';
}
else {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`name`, `mail`, `gender`, `message`) VALUES('".$name."','".$mail."','".$gender."','".$message."')");

    if($query) {
        echo '<div class="success">Congratulations You Are Registered Successfully</div>';
        echo '<a href="users.php">View Records</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'not';
    }
}
```

Comment: i am really thankful to you dear sir.your solution is working fine.loads of thanks.hats off to you

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to mark the answer as "Accepted" since it did help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I write validation code such as this I try to avoid using conditionals that check so many things at once.  Instead, validate each input in turn and abort if that is not valid; returning an error to the user at that point.  Then you could move all of this validation to a single sub-routine.  In this routine, if any validation checks fail - it returns immediately with an error.  Only if your sub-routine makes it to the end would a user be created.  And it prevents one from checking a variable `$mail` and then later validating it *after* it's already passed your truth check.